# HTML: Is there a way to display a link preview when setting innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, innerhtml

I'm setting the innerHtml property of an element using javascript. This is the innerHtml I'm setting which sends the link in an a-tag so that it's clickable:

```
description.forEach((pair) => {
   const [name, link] = pair;
   const htmlLink = `<a href=${link}>${link}</a><br><br>`
   const htmlPair = [name, htmlLink]
   joinedDescription.push(htmlPair.join(" "))
})
```

It's being displayed like this:
[image]

Is there a way to have the link preview displayed so it looks like this instead:[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and is a huge work.

Comment: To create a new line, just join with `<br>`. so: `htmlPair.join("<br>")` But if you are specifically talking about the description part, that will require you to fetch each url and get some sort of text from it (assuming the meta description exists is one way to do it), or add it to your array manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for HTML itself, no there is no way to do that. Somebody created that the CSS for links to be displayed like that. There might be some libraries that do that, but I'm not sure. Unfortunately, you probably have to make it your own. For the video, you have to use JavaScript to check if a link is a YouTube video and embedded properly in iframe (use embed from YouTube). For the other links, you have to get the title / meta data and wrap it in a CSS container.